# SwiftUI text doesn't fit when have length property change

Tags: text, swiftui, sizetofit

Increase or decrease Int with buttons. When going from positive numbers to negative numbers or when a facto 10 is added sizeToFit cannot handle.

Solution (?)
Looks like it is a discrepancy between Preview and Simulator/Device. Maybe I should file a radar instead...

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var totalClicked: Int = 0

```
var body: some View {

    VStack {

        HStack {
            Button(action: {self.totalClicked = self.totalClicked - 1}) {
                Text("decrease")
            }
            Button(action: {self.totalClicked = self.totalClicked + 1}) {
                Text("increase")
            }
        }.padding()
        Text("\(totalClicked)")


    }
}
```

}[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Simulator <-> Preview discrepancy
[image]

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and it worked completely fine. The `Text` properly adjusts with negative numbers and with numbers longer than 1 digit.